# Update jTextField using binding

Tags: java, eclipse, binding, refresh, jtextfield

I am creating a graphical interface that presents a JTextField and other elements.
I have created a class with inside :
a field String
a method that appends the results from sql queries to the field string

I have created the bindings between the string field of this class and the text of the JTextField , but I can not dynamically update the object JTextField.

What is the best practice in this case? any suggestions?
thanks

This is the code of class:

public class firstStatistics {
    private String result;

```
public void getResult(String mese, String anno){    
    result = "targets_ais_ship_class_a_all_aaaammgg \n";
    result += "Num di giorni:\t" + nDays + "\n";
    try {
        /*
         Connection with DB
        */
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        //for(int i=1;i<=nDays;i++){
            for(int i=1;i<=1;i++){
            // create and execute a SELECT
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("****" + anno + nMonth + getStringDay(i));

            rs.next();
            result += getStringDay(i)+"/"+ mese + "/"+ anno + ":\t" + rs.getInt(1) + "\t Time(ms): " + elasped + "\n";
        }
        // close statement and connection
    } catch (java.lang.Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

this is code of GUI:
public class maresStatisticsGui {

```
private JFrame frmMaresStatistics;
private JTextField txtAnno;
private JTextField txtLat1;
private JTextField txtLong1;
private JTextField txtLat2;
private JTextField txtLong2;
private static firstStatistics fs;
private JTextArea txtResult;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    fs = new firstStatistics();
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                maresStatisticsGui window = new maresStatisticsGui();
                window.frmMaresStatistics.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}


/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public maresStatisticsGui() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frmMaresStatistics = new JFrame();
    frmMaresStatistics.setTitle("Mares Statistics");
    frmMaresStatistics.setBounds(100, 100, 609, 487);
    frmMaresStatistics.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frmMaresStatistics.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    frmMaresStatistics.getContentPane().add(panel);
    panel.setLayout(null);

    JLabel lblMese = new JLabel("Mese");
    panel.add(lblMese);

    Choice choice = new Choice();
    panel.add(choice);
    choice.add("");
    choice.add("Gennaio");
    //...

    JLabel lblAnno = new JLabel("Anno(aaaa)");
    panel.add(lblAnno);

    txtAnno = new JTextField();
    txtAnno.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 15));
    panel.add(txtAnno);
    panel.revalidate();
    panel.repaint();

    JPanel panel_2 = new JPanel();
    panel_2.setBorder(new TitledBorder(UIManager.getBorder("TitledBorder.border"), "Risultato", TitledBorder.LEADING, TitledBorder.TOP, null, new Color(0, 0, 0)));
    frmMaresStatistics.getContentPane().add(panel_2);
    panel_2.setLayout(null);

    txtResult = new JTextArea();
    panel_2.add(txtResult);

    JButton btnRicerca = new JButton("Ricerca");
    btnRicerca.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            fs.getResult("Febbraio", "2015");
        }
    });
    frmMaresStatistics.getContentPane().add(btnRicerca);

}

protected void initDataBindings() {
    BeanProperty<firstStatistics, String> firstStatisticsBeanProperty = BeanProperty.create("result");
    BeanProperty<JTextArea, String> jTextAreaBeanProperty = BeanProperty.create("text");
    AutoBinding<firstStatistics, String, JTextArea, String> autoBinding = Bindings.createAutoBinding(UpdateStrategy.READ, fs, firstStatisticsBeanProperty, txtResult, jTextAreaBeanProperty);
    autoBinding.bind();
}
```

}

When i call fs.getResult("Febbraio", "2015"), this method writes on string "result" of class "firstStatistics", but the jtextarea does not refresh.

thanks

Comment: please share your code

Answer (score 0):

Hitting in blind since you haven't shared any code that you are trying::

You can use setText on textfiled, the string where you are appending the results.

Comment: I can not use the setText ( ) method , because I can not see the variable "result " of the other class.

Comment: You are already doing   fs.getResult("Febbraio", "2015");. Get it in some variable or set to TextField.setText(  fs.getResult("Febbraio", "2015"));

Comment: The method fs.getResult("Febbraio", "2015") takes a lot of time, about 10 minutes. In this time the "result" vatiable of the first class is frequently updated and it's used like a container of the result of query. I need that the jTextField is refreshed when the variable change his state, and no at the end of the  fs.getResult("Febbraio", "2015").

Comment: I have tried to write on jTextField using a temporized thread, but it doesn't work and the jTextField does not update.is it possible that the problem is the refresh screen of monitor? I've also tried to write jTextField.revalidate(); jTextField.repaint();jTextField.dolayout() but the result is the same....